# Merging values from source xml and variable using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have two inputs for transformation.

One is source XML `source.xml` and looks like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>FooBar</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>Bar</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>3</id>
        <value>FooFoo</value>
    </row>
</ROOT>
```

Other one is supplied through parameter (`<xsl:param name="input" />`) into transformation. Structure is same as a XML above. But contains different number of rows and different values.

```
<ROOT>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>Foo</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>Bar</value>
    </row>
</ROOT>
```

Now I need to merge those inputs. I want to iterate over `source.xml` and for each row's id decide if there is same id in variable and update. If there is not same id in variable `$input` I want to create new row. 
In other words: `source.xml` represents new data while input parameter represents data I already have. And I want them to merge. I think you get it.

I tried many ways to solve this, but I always stucked on comparing ids with creating unnecessary rows. The restrictions are those:

- XSLT 1.0 limitation.
- input for comparison can be imported only by using XSLT parameter.

Output should look like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>FooBar</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
        <value>Bar</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>3</id>
        <value>FooFoo</value>
    </row>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Well what type does your parameter have? A node set, a result tree fragment, a string with XML markup? Only showing `<xsl:param name="input" />` does not tell us what kind of type your parameter will have.

Comment: Well, that is hard to tell because parameter is supplied automatically from engine and I have no control over it. I supposed it is node set or string with XML markup. I know I can invoke templates over it and run XPath expressions. I hope it helps

Comment: If you can use XPath then it is a node set. Why does the output have `<row>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>Updated</value>
    </row>` and not `<row>
        <id>1</id>
        <value>Foo</value>
    </row>` if the `source.xml` represents the new data?

Comment: I messed it up. Now it should be ok. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the supplied parameter is indeed a node-set, then you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="input" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$input/ROOT/row[not(id = current()/row/id)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```